# In Python: How can i get my code to print out all the possible words I can spell based on my input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I was close to figuring out how to print out all the possible words based on user input from my set dictionary. it's based on the assumption that the user input is 'ART' so the possible words I have in my dictionary are ART, RAT, TART, and TAR but only the three letter combinations are printing out. can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks!

```
Dictionary = ["tar","art","tart","rat"] #creates dictionary of set words
StoredLetters = input('input your word here: ') #allows the user to input any word
list(StoredLetters)

def characters(word):
    Dictionary = {}
    for i in word:
        Dictionary[i] = Dictionary.get(i, 0) + 1
    return Dictionary

def all_words(StoredLetters, wordSet):
    for word in StoredLetters:
        flag = 1
        words = characters(word)
        for key in words:
            if key not in wordSet:
                flag = 0
            else:
                if wordSet.count(key) != words[key]:
                    flag = 0
        if flag == 1:
            print(word)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(all_words(Dictionary, StoredLetters))
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the following inputs: `"artt"`, `"arte"`, `"arttt"` given the above dictionary?

Comment: for artt just tart
for arte just none since there is no word with e in the dictionary
for arttt none as well since no words have 3 t

Comment: OK, so in other words, you can use a letter more than once, but you can't ignore letters. Thanks, that helps clarify.

Comment: That is correct! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the follow-up comments, the rule is that we must use all characters in the target word, but we can use each character as many times as we want.

I'd set up the lookup "dictionary" data structure as a Python `dict` which maps sorted, unique characters as tuples in each dictionary word to a list of the actual words that can be formed from those characters.

Next, I'd handle the lookups as follows:

- Sort the unique characters of the user input (target word) and index into the dictionary to get the list of words it could make. Using a `set` means that we allow repetition and sorting the characters means we normalize for all of the possible permutations of those letters.
- The above alone can give false positives, so we filter the resulting word list to remove any actual result words that are shorter than the target word. This ensures that we handle a target word like `"artt"` correctly and prevent it from matching `"art"`.

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Dictionary:
    def __init__(self, words):
        self.dictionary = defaultdict(list)

        for word in words:
            self.dictionary[tuple(sorted(set(word)))].append(word)

    def search(self, target):
        candidates = self.dictionary[tuple(sorted(set(target)))]
        return [x for x in candidates if len(x) >= len(target)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dictionary = Dictionary(["tar", "art", "tart", "rat"])
    tests = ["art", "artt", "ar", "arttt", "aret"]

    for test in tests:
        print(f"{test}\t=> {dictionary.search(test)}")
```

Output:

```
art     => ['tar', 'art', 'tart', 'rat']
artt    => ['tart']
ar      => []
arttt   => []
aret    => []
```

The issues in the original code have been addressed nicely in the other answers. The logic doesn't seem clear since it's comparing characters to words and variable names often don't match the logic represented by the code.

It's fine to use a frequency counter, but you'll be stuck iterating over the dictionary, and you'll need to check that each count of a character in a dictionary word is greater than the corresponding count in the target word. I doubt the code I'm offering is optimal, but it should be much faster than the counter approach, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are a few things that could contribute to this.

1. You are swapping the parameters on all words `def allwords(Dictionary, StoredLetters):` when you call it in main `allwords(StoredLetters, Dictionary)`. Without specifying the name (look up named parameters in python) you would be swapping the input.
2. In the `characters` function it would appear you are resetting the dictionary variable. Try using unique names when creating new variables. This is causing the dictionary of words you set at the top to be emptied out when `characters(word)` is called

Comment: Thanks! I updated so my variables are more unique, I can see why that would be important now and how it makes it convoluted. Great suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are confusing things by having the name of your variable `StoredLetters` also being the name of one of the arguments to your `all_words` function.

Second, you are actually passing in `StoredLetters`, which is `art`, as the 2nd argument to the function, so it is `wordSet` in the function, not `StoredLetters`!

You should really keep things more clear by using different variable names, and making it obvious what are you using for which argument. `words` isn't really words, it's a dictionary with letters as keys, and how many times they appear as the values! Making code clear and understandable goes a long way to making it easy to debug. You have `word`, `StoredLetters`, `wordSet`, another `StoredLetters` argument, `words = characters(word)` which doesn't do what is expected. This could all use a good cleanup.

As for the functionality, with `art`, each letter only appears once, so for `tart`, which has `t` twice, `if wordSet.count(key) != words[key]` will evaluate as True, and flag will be set to 0, and the word will not be printed.

Hope that helps, and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, for clean up I guess I am a little lost on how I would make it more neat aside from clearing up the issue with StoredLetters (done and changed).

I really like and appreciate the explanation you gave me for functionality, I changed != to > and that seams to have worked but II'm not sure if that change really works cause when I type in 'arte' for input I am expecting the output of None but it actually gives me all four words of my dictionary in the output. 

either way, thanks so much as this did help move me along in the right direction.

Comment: I think you need a clear statement of what you want the functionality to be. Is it to find all words that can be made with your input letters? Can you use a letter more than once? Are you allowed to have extra letters? So as you wrote in your comment, if you type in `arte` you want that to return `None`, but for `art` you want `rat` AND `tart`? So letters can be used more than once, but there can't be any extra letters that aren't used? It makes a big difference, and will help point you toward a solution.<p>btw, if you liked my answer, please upvote and select as correct as desired! Thanks!